# Real time react web app with pusher and laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, pusher

I want to use pusher for realtime chat and it works properly  with public channel but when I use private channel I got this error :

```
pusher.js:1333 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://20.30.0.236:8000/login with MIME type text/html
```

this is laravel code :

Event :

```
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public $user;
public $message;

public function __construct(User $user, Message $message)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->message = $message;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('chat');
}
```

channels.php :

```
    Broadcast::channel('private-chat', function ($user) {
    return true;
});
```

BroadcastServiceProvider :

```
  class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

and this is react js code :

```
  export const onChatRcv = () => {
    try {
        Pusher.logToConsole = true;

        var pusher = new Pusher('83*********63c912f5', {
            cluster: 'ap2',
            forceTLS: true,
            authTransport: 'jsonp',
            authEndpoint: `${baseUrl}broadcasting/auth`,
            headers: {
                'Authorization' : `Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjRhZTA1YjM2ZGNhN2I5NWI4NTJiZjFhOWRiZTQ5ZWE1NzFmNTNkMTE4NWQyOWU0Mjk0ZDI5NmJmZThhZTE0OGQzNzcwODM1MjEzYTg2NzA1In0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiNGFlMDViMzZkY2E3Yjk1Yjg1MmJmMWE5ZGJlNDllYTU3MWY1M2QxMTg1ZDI5ZTQyOTRkMjk2YmZlOGFlMTQ4ZDM3NzA4MzUyMTNhODY3MDUiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTExMDQ3NTYsIm5iZiI6MTU1MTEwNDc1NiwiZXhwIjoxNTgyNjQwNzU2LCJzdWIiOiI1Iiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.HOnNyhQQ48Hj4AZdP5vS5Zd5AfUr5XNP4zgrgR_f2-aAgFw4eWrNeHQSfdJt071_ChRINmv5W7O1LExxGIvCoSjiYFYPmw_8WjdFI_81WHoqM69ve-bgriK6eO1Yf0N3v3fc1DvPk2ZFYXXDmQbMLLXUyUqfjoYGty8AMgxCDulZ1tRMZ2rOVQZJ0ePbTw1eHQdMzBWG36fXWEbczLR99-_Dn8ta8P6iq0XWDr0cimlFzdHsG66iMeI0xWCJ1DRbxzr2LuX0j5zKe0j0_WNZJNbAFfeY87m7FDHjbHTNB1IB9Meh8kITV1mPQLc2n812j2QgW19KKWgpgZcy4tlfIBfT0x-aQAMkIUtmcHW0aEJ8RkHWKZYhyQ8yV61RIL3IxLpepHUVds8CZnxDGQ2NQ4bmb8UE7xQkV-KpmF5fZ0NCCxMuMpYdVkd0t9gc_Jra07_Sq7HbEJHEZbPCfhbDscAZQr2U9ddVaKwiGuFjSGXvOKS_lUAB91lBWada3k15FG2XoBfAv94mai2aWo41sep0nmlBKXPCVbWiczbeNL6ZXm_aE-tkLNS-Pc0veXogxZIaKVhFnRsW5qHTXI8v6sU6Nd9pzrIe173FqXQtzpA_tqrmdWU-lU-u484hWkPn2OcQcSckANpx-7_EVhrAPSfV7-WWamMRp2EC-3uFpmQ`,
            },
        });

        var privateChannel = pusher.subscribe('private-chat' );
        privateChannel.bind('App\\Events\\MessageSent', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

what is the problem?
it works when we use public channel but in private channel, we got this warning

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://20.30.0.236:8000/login with MIME type text/html
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default route `broadcasting/auth` can't retrieve a suitable response so I added the custom `authEndPoint`.

`web.php`:

```
Route::get('pusher/auth', 'PusherController@pusherAuth');
```

and added `PusherController`:

```
class PusherController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Authenticates logged-in user in the Pusher JS app
     * For presence channels
     */
    public function pusherAuth()
    {

        $user = auth()->user();

        if ($user) {
            $pusher = new Pusher('auth-key', 'secret', 'app_id');
            $auth= $pusher->socket_auth(Input::get('channel_name'), Input::get('socket_id'));
            $callback = str_replace('\\', '', $_GET['callback']);
            header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
            echo($callback . '(' . $auth . ');');
            return;
        }else {
            header('', true, 403);
            echo "Forbidden";
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This works and subscribes the channel.

Answer (score 4):

You can think of accessing a private channel as if you are making a private auth request to the server .
You Cant Directly Access A private channel from react Because of Security Reasons.
As Mentioned In [CodeAcademy](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-cors) ....

> Servers are used to host web pages, applications, images, fonts, and much more. When you use a web browser, you are likely attempting to access a distinct website (hosted on a server). Websites often request these hosted resources from different locations (servers) on the Internet. Security policies on servers mitigate the risks associated with requesting assets hosted on different server

You Need a policy in your laravel app to add CORS (CROSS ORIGIN REQUEST SHARING )
Initially It was a bit complicated But You can use this [library](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors).

Now You can make any kind of private requests to your laravel app.

**PS**

Dont Forget to add checks in your broadcasts routes in channels.php as you are just simply returning true without any checks.